# Email download problem in Outlook and Exchange

Tags: email, exchange-2007, outlook

folks!  Our company has an Exchange 2007 Mail Server and we have several users who use Outlook to access their emails.  One particular user, Jim, is using Outlook 2003 to access his emails and he has a problem.  He also uses a smart phone (that uses Exchange Sync) and Outlook Web Access to check his emails.  If he opens an email using Outlook 2003, it removes the email from his phone and Outlook Web Access.  If he uses the latter two to check email, they remain in that application until he opens Outlook 2003 on his computer and the emails are removed from his phone and Outlook Web Access.  Do you have any thoughts on what I should check?  Thanks, in advance, for your help!
Sincerely,
Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem: The Email account was set up so that new emails would be delivered to a location on his C: drive, and not the server.  I'm sorry for taking all your time.  I hope my solution helps someone else in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like email is setup as a POP account in his Outlook.  All you need to do is reconfigure his outlook account as exchange and that should fix his issues.  Tools > email accounts > view/change > and look at his account type to verify.

If you do not want to change his account type in outlook you can modify his POP account to not remove email by going to the account settings > more settings > advanced and check "leave a copy of messages on the server".

Comment: Thanks, but it is not set as a POP account.

Comment: He may be delivering mail to a local .pst file then.  Go to same location and select his mail account.  Near the bottom of that window it should say "deliver email to following location".  Make sure it is leaving it in the exchange folders and not directing it to a local .pst